# Is xfire client proxy thread safe?

Tags: java, web-services, concurrency, xfire

When developing an application which consumes an external webservice I have generated the sources from the wsdl-url and then created a client:

```
GeoIPServiceClient service = new GeoIPServiceClient();
GeoIPServiceSoap geoIPClient = service.getGeoIPServiceSoap();
```

Since the creation of this proxy takes some time I set the client as an attribute in my service class.

But I'm worried that the client isn't thread safe and this webservice is heavily used in the application by concurrent threads (webapp). I can't find any documentation on this.

As a precaution I've started to use an object pool of soap clients instead of a shared one.

Is this an unnecessary precaution? What is the best practice when writing xfire clients?

I suspect some kind of concurrency problem with xfire since I regularly, under high load, get blocked threads and as a result of this the application crashes. Here's a partial thread dump:

```
"http-xx.xx.xx.xx-80-17" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f560d437000 nid=0x66cb waiting for monitor entry [0x00000000412b8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:174)
    - waiting to lock <0x00007f561d44e1c0> (a com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.<init>(TransducedAccessor.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:173)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor165.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:481)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:277)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.jaxb2.JaxbType.getJAXBContext(JaxbType.java:306)
    - locked <0x00007f565b3aee60> (a org.codehaus.xfire.jaxb2.JaxbType)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.jaxb2.JaxbType.writeObject(JaxbType.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.aegis.AegisBindingProvider.writeParameter(AegisBindingProvider.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.AbstractBinding.writeParameter(AbstractBinding.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.WrappedBinding.writeMessage(WrappedBinding.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.soap.SoapSerializer.writeMessage(SoapSerializer.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel.writeWithoutAttachments(HttpChannel.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.OutMessageRequestEntity.writeRequest(OutMessageRequestEntity.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender.send(CommonsHttpMessageSender.java:369)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel.sendViaClient(HttpChannel.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel.send(HttpChannel.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.handler.OutMessageSender.invoke(OutMessageSender.java:26)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline.invoke(HandlerPipeline.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Client.invoke(Client.java:336)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.client.XFireProxy.handleRequest(XFireProxy.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.client.XFireProxy.invoke(XFireProxy.java:57)
    at $Proxy143.getMyMethod(Unknown Source)
```

The thread dump contains a lot of blocked threads that look like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess as you get a lot of blocked threads, the client is actually thread-safe as object data is not corrupted :). But I agree it's not handling the concurrency in a good way.

1) One observation is that the final lock seems to be in JAXB implementation and not in XFire. What if you try using different JAXB implementation like [JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/)?

2) Also the method getJAXBContext in [JaxbType](https://svn.codehaus.org/xfire/trunk/xfire/xfire-jaxb2/src/main/org/codehaus/xfire/jaxb2/JaxbType.java) is synchronised. And most likely because your threads are accessing the same JaxbType instance they may be blocked.

Looking at that method I would actually moved the synchronisation into the method after context presense is checked:

```
if (context == null) {
    synchronized (this)  {
         ...
```

This will allow for clients that already have JAXBContext initialised to skip expensive synchronisation.

My suggestion is either try fixing the code yourself and make a test or submit a bug to XFire or do both :).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the version of Xfire you are using, as they have fixed few Thread Safety issues in version 1.2.5. You can check the bug raised at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XFIRE-886 , and see more details on the release notes at hxxp://xfire.codehaus.org/XFire+1.2.5+Release+Notes